# AS3: What resolvePath should I use for my AIR application?

Tags: ios, windows, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am working on an simple AIR app. 
And used:

```
File.userDirectory.nativePath.toString();
```

Here, I have kept my external images into a folder called "INTERFACE".

After publishing, I have removed the image folder. 
And images are not loading in my APP.

So like to know, What

> resolvePath

shoud I use for my AIR application?

**PS: I am using MAC, I am not sure about WINDOWS.**

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. You can use any path with `resolvePath`, it's totally up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images wont load because you are targeting

```
File.userDirectory.nativePath.toString();
```

but you dont have the directory there, because you have deleted that. So your app must create "INTERFACE" directory in userDirectory and then access it. You can read More about the file handling at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html, It have explanation for both platform